# UIKit navbar not working tried CDN and compiling LESS

Tags: navbar, getuikit

Trying the clickmode example from here https://getuikit.com/docs/navbar I get this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWUzM.png

I can't get the grid to work either. It's so simple. How could it not work?

(See the dropdown is open by default. jQuery is included.)

Comment: What exactly is 'not working'? I can see the attached image, but what is it about that result that is not what you expected?